# SQL Server 2005 Cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, cursor

what are some of the cases that will cause a SQL Server 2005 cursor to deallocate prematurely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing comes to mind: a [sufficiently severe (20+) error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937483%28SQL.80%29.aspx) being raised on the connection will blow away the entire connection -- cursors, local temporary tables and all.